# Charge on a conducting sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

As far as I know, to have a net flex through a closed surface there must be a charge inside it. However, what if I have for example a conducting sphere where the charge accumulate on the surface, will the net flux through the sphere and the electric field on the surface be zero?

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct - there will be no net flux through the sphere. Inside the sphere, there will be no electric field. Just on the surface, however, there will be an electric field (directed outwards) due to the charge spread over it.